# "Network Error" on page change in Android Emulator, with Cordova/PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, android-emulator

When I run my Cordova app in the simulator, it loads alright (albeit extremely slowly, which is apparently a common complaint). I'm using jQuery Mobile, and owing to certain problems I have with JQM's form methods and also to conflicts between JQM and Google Maps, my app is structured such that certain pages cause a whole DOM reload rather than the AJAX transition JQM normally induces. The app is taken to a separate html file entirely.

This works fine in iOS, but when I run it in the Android Emulator, I get "Application Error: A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/nameOfPageIWasGoingTo.html?parameter1=34¶meter2=true)"

Cordova is re-included on each of these pages, and I placed the line

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

in my main .java file so that now the onCreate thing looks like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Nevertheless, I have this error. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Android where the WebView fails to load pages if you try to pass parameters in the URL. Android is treating *"nameOfPageIWasGoingTo.html?parameter1=34¶meter2=true"* as a file name when it should load *"nameOfPageIWasGoingTo.html"* and pass the parameters along to the page. In the meantime you should use localStorage.setItem/getItem to pass parameters between pages.

In the mean time you should go star these issues:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient

```
@Override
    public void init() {
    super.init(webView, new IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(this, webView), new CordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This network error shows up for various reasons, but my guess is that your config.xml is looking for index.html and you have named your html page something else. ("nameOfPageIWasGoingTo.html")

Answer (score 0):

Dont use querystring parameters, use window.localStorage instead. A little bit late but confirmed =).